# Conditional formatting: IF contains XX OR YY OR ZZ

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

So im making a spreadsheet for fun but I need some help because it would be generous to say my experience is amateur level.

I want to change the color of the cell to the same color if they contain one of a range of different values (all string text)

Example: If cell contains "XXX" or "YYY" or "ZZZ" then colorchange =true, else color = white

I don't really want to have to make separate rules for each string because theres about 80 of them in total

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

use custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, "XXX|YYY|ZZZ")
```

note its case sensitive so to turn off the sensitivity do:

```
=REGEXMATCH(UPPER(A1), "XXX|YYY|ZZZ")
```

you can also put your 80 values in a column and use:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Z:Z))
```

where Z:Z contains all your values

if you want to put those values on a different sheet use:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!Z:Z")))
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your quick reply. One thing I forgot to mention is that the string condition wont be an exact match but I still need it to return true.
example: I need XXXabc to return true for XXX

Comment: these all formulas are for partial match. the exact match is done differently